# How to redirect unauthenticated user to a page without credential prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

My local ASP.Net Core 3.1 web app is deployed on IIS and have windows authentication enabled only.

How do I redirect unauthenticated users to a view without the credential prompt popping up? E.g. go to PublicIndex **without prompting user to enter loging details**. Is that possible?

Do I need to implement custom attribute/filter to intercept the request like below or can I do some sort of route configuration in Startup.cs?

```
// Private page for authenticated users
[RedirectToPublicIndexIfNotAuthenticated]
public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticatedIndex()
{
    return View();
}

// Public page for anonymous users
public async Task<IActionResult> PublicIndex()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Basic Authentication is very insecure for that matter. What you want is Single Sign On. You would need some SAML construction for that f.i. using ADFS.

Comment: Users who failed IIS side Windows authentication are responded with 401.1 error page. You can customize that on IIS to redirect to a page you like.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two different ways that you have in this situation;** But as the first solution is going to change the *option.LoginPath* value to the action that you want unauthorized users be redirected - located in *services.AddAuthentication()* method in *StartUp.cs* - it is not a good idea(Because it might make some problems for your *Login* action).

**So that I would highly recommend you to use the second solution with following these steps...**

You must have used *Claims* specifications for logging in your users, so whenever an authorized user tries to get into your actions, you have already saved up his username, email or these pieces of information. Here is an example of saving up user's account information using *Claims* when logging in...

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
        };
```

As you can see, we can access the authorized user's username whenever we want, using the `User.Identity.Name` variable.But if the user is not authorized it will give us a null value.

By using this trick, you can control and redirect your users in every action that you want

```
// Private page for authorized users
[Authorized]
public IActionResult AuthenticatedIndex()
{
    #region Conditions
    
    if (User.Identity.Name == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("PublicIndex", "Home", new { area = "" });
    }

    #endregion

    return View();
}

// Public page for anonymous users
public IActionResult PublicIndex()
{
    return View();
}
```

Hope it was useful,
good luck!